# if $y,z$ converges to zero, does $yz \rightarrow 0 \,\, \text{in} \, L^2(\Omega)$ as well?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $y,z \in L^2(\Omega)$ such that
$$y \rightarrow 0 \,\, \text{in} \, L^2(\Omega)$$
$$z \rightarrow 0 \,\, \text{in} \, L^2(\Omega)$$

can we deduce that $yz \rightarrow 0 \,\, \text{in} \, L^2(\Omega)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Can you find $y \in L^{2}$ such that $y^{2} \notin L^{2}$? Once you have such a $y$ take $y_n=z_n=\frac  y n$.

Comment: I see thank's for the example, and what about if $y_n \rightarrow 0$ and $z \in L^2(\Omega)$ ?